# Nav Menu Not Showing In Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Please help! This project is for a job. I have built a navigation menu that displays fine in Chrome and Safari, the other required browser is Firefox, but the navigation menu isn't displaying at all.

Here is my code:

```
<body>  
    <div class="main">
        <header>
            <a href="index.html"><div id="logo"></div></a>
            <nav id="login">
                <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
            </nav>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <nav id="menu">
                <li><a href="household.html">Household</a></li>
                <li><a href="toys.html">Toys</a></li>
                <li><a href="pets.html">Pets</a></li>
                <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
                <li><a href="electronics.html">Electronics</a></li>
            </nav>
            <!-- Slider -->
            <div class="slider-wrapper">
                <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                    <img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="PS4">
                    <img src="images/image2.jpg" alt="PS4">
                    <img src="images/image3.jpg" alt="PS4">
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(window).load(function() {
                    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
                });
            </script>
            <!-- Slider -->
        </header>   
        <section class="content">
            <h1>Household</h1>
            <section id="iowbg">
                <img id="iowimage" src="./images/iow_lamp_2.jpg">
                <div class="productname"><h2>Ikea Orgel Vreten Floor Lamp, Natural, Steel</h2></div>
                <div class="productdesc"><h5>Shade of handmade paper, each shade is unique. Gives a soft mood light.</h5></div>
                <div class="productprice"><h2 style="color: #900;">$19.99</h2></div>
            </section>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <section id="discounts">
                <h2>Discounted Items</h2>
                <figure id="discountsitem">
                    <img id="discountsimage" src="./images/discount_01.jpg" alt="">
                    <figcaption class="discountdesc">
                        Office Star 4-Foot Resin Multipurpose Table, Light Grey
                    </figcaption>
                    <figcaption class="regularprice">
                        $49.99
                    </figcaption>
                    <figcaption class="discountprice">
                        $39.99
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
                <figure id="discountsitem">
                    <img id="discountsimage" src="./images/discount_02.jpg" alt="">
                    <figcaption class="discountdesc">
                        Aquarius Aq15005 Aquarius 5 Rounded 5-Gallon Aquarium Kit
                    </figcaption>
                    <figcaption class="regularprice">
                        $29.99
                    </figcaption>
                    <figcaption class="discountprice">
                        $19.99
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
                <figure id="discountsitem"> 
                    <img id="discountsimage" src="./images/discount_03.jpg" alt="">
                    <figcaption class="discountdesc">
                        Intex Pull-out Sofa
                    </figcaption>
                        <figcaption class="regularprice">
                            $54.99
                        </figcaption>
                        <figcaption class="discountprice">
                            $44.99
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </section>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <a href="household.html"><img class="imageset" src="images/01_household.jpg"></a>
            <a href="toys.html"><img class="imageset" src="images/02_toys.jpg"></a>
            <a href="pets.html"><img class="imageset" src="images/03_pets.jpg"></a>
            <a href="music.html"><img class="imageset" src="images/04_music.jpg"></a>
            <a href="electronics.html"><img class="imageset" src="images/05_electronics.jpg"></a>
            <form id="contact">
                <h1>Contact Us</h1>
                <label id="firstName" class="label">First Name: </label>
                <input type="text" class="TextInput" value="Your First Name"></label><br>
                <label id="lastName" class="label">Last Name: </label>
                <input type="text" class="TextInput" value="Your Last Name"></label><br>
                <label id="userEmail" class="label">Your Email: </label>
                <input type="email" class="EmailInput" value="Your Email Address"><br>
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">                 
            </form>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </footer>
        <small>&copy; 2013, Our Stuff Is Cheap But Good Co. | All Rights Reserved</small>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #404040;
}
a {
color: #404040;
text-decoration: none;
transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
-webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.sectionheader {
color: #1046a9;
}
p {
font-size: 12px;
}
.content {
padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
a:hover {
color: #5bbb15;
text-decoration: none;
transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
-webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
}
body {
background-image: url('../images/body_bg.png');
background-repeat: repeat;
}
.main {
margin: auto;
padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
width: 960px;
}
#logo {
background-image: url('../images/logo_3.png');
float: left;
height: 100px;
width: 148px;
margin-bottom: -43px;
}
#login {
float: right;
font-size: 12px;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: right;
}
#login li {
display: inline;
padding-left: 20px;
}
.clear {
height: 1px;
width: 100%;
}
#menu, #menu ul, #menu li, #menu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
#menu {
    height: 40px;
    width: 380px;
float: right;
margin-bottom: 20px; 
    background: #4c4e5a;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#menu li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
}
#menu ul { display: none; }
#menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 14px;
    margin: 6px 0;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #393942;
    border-right: 1px solid #4f5058;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #f3f3f3;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}
#menu li:first-child a { border-left: none; }
#menu li:last-child a{ border-right: none; }
#menu li:hover > a { color: #78fe3f !important; }
#menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #1f2024;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}
#menu li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; }
#menu ul li {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}
#menu li:hover > ul li {
    height: 36px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
}
#menu ul li a {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 40px;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #353539;
}
#menu ul li:last-child a { border: none; }
footer { border-bottom: solid 1px #5bbb15; border-top: solid 1px #5bbb15; }
footer small { font-size: 12px;}
#contact {
float: right;
margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

label {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #404040;
font-size: 14px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: right;
}
.TextInput {
width: 300px;
border-radius: 4px;
margin-left: 10px;
color: #bfbfbf;
}
.EmailInput {
width: 300px;
border-radius: 4px;
margin-left: 10px;
color: #bfbfbf;
}
.button {
width: 308px;
float: right;
}
.imageset {
margin: 30px 4px 0 0;
border: none;
}
#iowbg {
background: #b3b3b3;
width: 920px;
height: 250px;
padding: 20px;
}
#iowimage {
float: left;
position: relative;
}
.productname, .productdesc, .productprice  {
position: relative;
text-align: left;
margin-left: 240px;
margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.productname {
margin-top: 26px;
}
.productprice {
width: 67px;
padding: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
float: left;
position: absolute;
margin-left: 240px;
}
#discountsitem{
float: left;
width: 320px;
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
}
.discountdesc {
width: 200px;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 14px;
}
.regularprice {
text-decoration: line-through;
color: #900;
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
}
.discountprice {
color: #5bbb15;
float: left;
}
.productsection {
width: 920px;
padding: 20px;
margin: 20px 0 20px 0 auto;
}
```

I have two navs and one of them is working just fine. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there's nothing visibly wrong with the HTML. It might be the CSS, but there's a small problem - you kinda didn't post it. Providing it would be much appreciated!

EDIT: OK, the two navbars I'm assuming you're referring two in your question are #login and #menu. I ran the HTML (with the CSS attached in the header as a style tag) and both of the navbars render fine in both Chrome and Firefox. I even screenshot it to make sure I wasn't dreaming. I would post the screenshot, but again, reputation deficit.

My only guess at right now would be that something's wrong with your Firefox. Unless, of course, I'm misunderstanding you completely. Then I'm gonna blame your communication skills. :P

Comment: Sorry I didn't post this in a comment, but as I'm new to the forum I don't have enough reputation to make comments on questions apparently.

Comment: Just posted the CSS, sorry about that :|

Comment: Haha! Well, I guess if could be a problem with my Firefox, but it's the #menu one that's not showing up. #login is showing up just fine, which makes me think that Firefox has no problems at all running HTML5 (obviously) it just doesn't like how I've arranged the #menu. I'll check to see if Firefox is up to date and see what happens.

Comment: OK, installed the latest version of Firefox and it's still not showing. Please help! This is due by EOD tomorrow. Thanks!